# Why is windows 8 - 32 bit that is running through Virtual box on mac is not using/showing the specified RAM?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, memory, osx-mountain-lion, macbook-pro

I have upgraded ram of my macbook pro to 16gb and I am running virtual box to run windows 8-32 bit. In settings, I have assigned 8192 mb of RAM but when I run windows and check the properties of my computer, it only shows 3.50 GB of RAM.

Have I done something wrong or am I missing something? Or is there any restriction for the memory one can assign to virtual machines on mac or in virtual-box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

32-bit versions of Windows are only capable of using up to 4 GB of RAM. You'll need to install a 64-bit version of Windows 8 in VirtualBox in order to use more. You're seeing 3.5 GB likely because of video memory or other things occupying the remaining 0.5 GB.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft limits the usable RAM of 32Bit client systems](http://www.geoffchappell.com/notes/windows/license/memory.htm) to [3.25 till 3.5GB](http://www.saferbytes.it/2012/08/06/x86-4gb-memory-limit-from-a-technical-perspective/). So you can install a 64 Bit Windows 8 or try this [bootloader](http://www.saferbytes.it/2013/02/28/saferbytes-x86-memory-bootkit-new-updated-build-is-out/) which bypasses the limitation:

[image: 32Bit Win8 using 6GB RAM]

The virtualbox graphic driver must support PAE, so there is no guarantee that it will work.